# Which version of this phrase is correct and why is there a 是 at the beginning?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, the typical grammar structure for Subject + verb + place/object is not being used.

In the text, he says:

> 马克西：这是我的马克笔。是我在一棵树下找到的。

I am confused on the second sentence. I would write it as 我找到在一棵树下的 or 我在一棵树找到. (no 是 at the beginning).

What grammar structure does the native text use to say "I found it under a tree," and why does it make sense? Additionally, can someone ascertain whether my grammar rephrase is correct or not, and why?

Answer (score 2):

> 这是我的马克笔。**是**我在一棵树下找到的。

This is a compound sentence - [复合句](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%8D%E5%90%88%E5%8F%A5).

In which, "是" is a relative pronoun - "which" or "that", that connects a "main clause" and a "relative clause". For example:

"This is the table **which** I bought."

- This is the table =  the main clause.
- I bought =  the relative clause.
- which =  the relative pronoun joining the two clauses.

For your example:

"这是我的马克笔。**是**我在一棵树下找到的。"

- This is my marker = the main clause.
- I found under the tree =  the relative clause.
- witch (是) = the relative pronoun joining the two clauses.

**Comment on your rephrases:**

The first rephrase - "我找到在一棵树下的", is completely ungrammatical.

The 2nd rephrase - "我在一棵树(1)找到(2)"

- 1. You can't find a pen in a tree, a specific location relative to the tree needs to be specified - either "上", "下", "旁" or "附近".
- 2. At the end of a declarative or assertive sentence, you shall add "的" to ascertain the action you have stated.

Answer (score 0):

> 马克西：这是我的马克笔。是我在一棵树下找到的。

是 doesn't start a sentence

是我在一棵树下找到的  is a dependent clause that adds information to the object "marker pen"

- The first thing about the marker is: "it is mine" (这是我的)
- The second thing about the marker is: "**which** I found under a tree" (**是**我在一棵树下找到**的**)

The correct sentence:

> 马克西：这是我的马克笔，是我在一棵树下找到的。 It is my marker that I found under a tree.

If you wrote "这是我在一棵树下找到的马克笔"  (This is a marker I found under a tree), it doesn't say the pen is now yours

Comment: So it needed to be in two different clauses to tell 1 the marker is mine and 2 where it was found? Would it be a run-on sentence if you tried to combine the two into one clause?

Comment: It would be a run-on sentence: 这是我在一棵树下找到的我的马克笔